Controlling motor with Raspberry Pi Pico and relays
I have a 12V motor which can be rotated forward or backward based on the polarity. I would like to control it with Raspberry Pi's GPIO ports. So that by switching 2 GPIO ports on Rpi I would be able to either run th emoto forward, backward or have it stopped.
From my understanding, the best for this purpose is to use 2 contact relay such as HK19F-2C, 3V and hook it up that it provides either positive or negative polarity to the motor.
I have however problem with figuring out how to connect the relay, motor and Rpi together. There will be separate 12V power source for the motors.
Could you please help me with figuring out how to connect everything together? I need a schematics how to connect this properly.


The only question you have is if we can help. Yes we can. But you have not said what help you need and with what exactly. Please ask a question about the subject itself. Edit a question in.

Hi @Justme. Thank you for your comment. I have clarified that I need help with the schematicts of the circuit.

So what help you need with the schematics? Also, driving relays with GPIO ports is such a common thing that there must be questions about that already, with answers. Have you tried to find similar questions, or why don't the already asked questions cover what you need?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

use a relay module, not just a relay ... you will require a relay module that contains a minimum of two relays

Shouldn't this one be on Raspberry Pi StackExchange?

Two relays are to be switched via two GPIO ports.
A dual-relay module should suffice.
Here's the schematic.

